# Different promise pathways in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to figure out a way to program a function such that it's able to handle different promise chain paths without duplicating code.

With a concrete example, I'll elaborate on this question.

I have a simple API that updates the profile of a user. It takes as an argument, a new email, or a new username, or both. If a username is supplied, I'd like to verify that it hasn't been taken with a function called `getExistingUser(username)` that returns a `promise` that resolves to the actual user data. Therefore, the code snippet would then be something like

```
if (body.newUserName) {
  getExistingUser(newUserName).then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) // return bad request error
    else sql.update(newInfo) // an object that contains username (and email)
  })
} else {
  sql.update(newInfo) // an object that contains new email only
}
```

The challenge now is that, the update to the user profile if a username is supplied will have to go into `getExistingUser().then()`. But if only the email is supplied, the **exact same code blob to update sql** will have to go after `getExistingUser`, resulting in code duplication. Is there a builder approach that would let me decide what promises to chain up so that this kind of code duplication can be avoided?

Comment: Make a function

Comment: Aluan Haddad is that the only way?

Comment: Yes. A function. By the way... you are not returning from your `.then` callback so your code is likely broken

Comment: The code is just for demonstrating purposes, sql.update isnt a real function so the code is broken

Comment: In this "simple API",  where is the logic to prevent different users having the same email address?

Comment: in this particular case it seems better to run single request and process failure code if any. otherwise user waits for twice longer. But you have to run validation on server-side in call related to `sql.update` anyway. So user wait longer and you run the same validation twice - not good.

Comment: @traktor53 that isnt the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

For situations like these I personally prefer to create a promisified validations function as well to keep my promise chains intact and prevent code duplication, for example

```
function saveUser(params) {
  return validateRequest(params)
    .then(function(validatedParams) {
      db.updateUser(validatedParams)
    })
}

function validateRequest(params) {
  if(!params.email && !params.username) return {}
  var parsedParams = {}
  var promises = []

  if(params.email) {
    parsedParams.email = params.email
    promises.push(getUserByEmail(parsedParams.email))
  }
  if(params.username) {
    parsedParams.username = params.username
    promises.push(getUserByUsername(parsedParams.username))   
  }

  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    if(results.length > 0) {
      throw new Error("Username or email already exists")
    } else {
      return parsedParams
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: This is a pretty clean approach, but won't the first return from validateRequest() fail when you try to call .then() on an empty object?

Comment: @kidmosey validateRequest ideally should always return the promise through `Promise.all` that promise can potentially return empty object, if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
(body.newUserName
  ? getExistingUser(newUserName).then(existingUser => {
      if (existingUser) throw new Error("400 Bad request");
      // else return undefined
    })
  : Promise.resolve(/* undefined */)
).then(() => {
  return sql.update(newInfo)
}, err => {
  // do something with the bad request errors
})
```

Even easier using `async`/`await`:

```
if (body.newUserName) {
  const existingUser = await getExistingUser(newUserName);
  if (existingUser) {
    throw …; // or return
  }
}
await sql.update(newInfo);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to scope everything inside an anonymous function and add local functions as callbacks.

```
(function() {
    getExistingUser(body.newUserName)
        .then(processUser, showErrorMessage);

    function processUser(user) {
    }

    function showErrorMessage() {
    }
})();
```

This will also be useful when your code gets more complex and you want more helpful stacktraces while debugging.

-- UPDATE

I just re-read your post and while my solution isn't exactly what you asked, it would be trivial to modify it for your purpose.  This also makes it extremely clear what is expected to happen.  If you find a user, do one thing, otherwise do something else.  If you need to do the same thing in both instances, then the clearest thing to do is to make another function and call it from both methods.  This isn't considered duplicating code.